# Collection Vs Array Performance wise

Tags: java

Could you please let me know **Performance wise** why **Array** is better than **Collection**?

Answer (score 7):

It is not. It will actually depend on the use you make of your container.

Some algorithms may run in O(n) on an array and in O(1) on another collection type (which implements the Collection interface).

- Think about removal of an item for instance. In that case, the array, even if a native type, would perform slower than the linked list and its method calls (which could be inlined anyway on some VMs): it runs in O(n) VS O(1) for a linked list
- Think about searching an element. It runs in 0(n) for an array VS O(log n) for a tree.

Some Collection implementations use an array to store their elements (ArrayList I think) so in that case performance will not be significantly different.

You should spend time on optimizing your algorithm (and make use of the various collection types available) instead of worrying of the pros/cons of an array VS Collection.

Comment: out of curiosity, which algos ?

Comment: removal of an item for instance.

Comment: i apologize for being unclear - i was actually looking for the O(log(n)) ones. im aware of the insertion/removal difference

Answer (score 3):

Many collections are wrappers for arrays.  This includes ArrayList, HashMap/Set, StringBuilder.  For optimised code, the performance difference of the operations is minimal except when you come to operations which are better suited to that data structure e.g. lookup of a Map is much faster than the lookup in an array.

Using generics for collections which are basically primitives can be slower, not because the collection is slower but the extra object creation and cache usage (as the memory needed can be higher)  This difference is usually too small to matter but if you are concerned about this you can use the Trove4J libraries which are wrappers for arrays of primitives instead of arrays of Objects.

Where collections are slower is when you use operations which they are not suitable for e.g. random access of a LinkedList, but sensible coding can avoid these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, because arrays are primitive data structures in Java. Accesses to them can be translated directly into native memory-access instructions rather than method calls.

That said, though, it's not entirely obvious that arrays will strictly outperform collections in all circumstances. If your code references collection variables where the runtime type can be monomorphically known at JIT-time, Hotspot will be able to inline the access methods, and where they are simple, can be just as fast since there's basically no overhead anyway.

Many of the collections' access methods are intrinsically more complex than array referencing, however. There is, for instance, no way that a `HashMap` will be as efficient as a simple array lookup, no matter how much Hotspot optimizes it.

Comment: "no way that a HashMap will be as efficient as a simple array lookup" <- true in the case of linear access (element n°N of the array/collection) but wrong in case of a simple loop. Again, depends on the use.

Comment: Naturally, but I was trying to speak about the basic performance of the primitive operations of the data structures, not about how they scale for the purposes of higher-level operations. About the constant time factor you remove in O-notation, that is.

Comment: If you are searching for a key, HashMap is typically O(1) where and an array lookup by key is O(N).

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Like I said above, I'm not speaking about how high-level operations scale. I'm speaking of the constant time factors for the primitive operations.

Comment: @Dolda2000 I am not saying I disagree with you. It wasn't clear to me what is high level vs low level operations esp when you are talking about an array.

Comment: Clearly, a key lookup is not a _primitive_ operation on an array. :)

Comment: For instance, insertion is a primitive operation according to me, and clearly unefficient in an array VS linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the two. ArrayList is an implementation, Collection is an interface. There might be different implementations for the Collection interface.

In practice the implementation is chosen which as the simple access to your data. Usually ArrayList if you need to loop through all elements. Hashtable if you need access by key.

Performance should be considered only after measurements are made. Then it is easy to change the implementation because the collection framework has common interfaces like the Collection interface.

Answer (score 0):

The question is which one to use and when?

An **array** is basically a fixed size collection of elements. The bad point about an array is that it is not resizable. But its constant size provides efficiency if you are clear with your element size. So arrays are better to use when you know the number of elements available with you.

**Collection**

**ArrayList** is another collection where the number of elements is resizable. So if you are not sure about the number of elements in the collection use an ArrayList. But there are certain facts to be considered while using ArrayLists.

- ArrayLists is not synchronized. So if there are multiple threads
  accessing and modifying the list, then synchronization might be
  required to be handled externally.
- ArrayList is internally implemented as an array. So whenever a new
  element is added an array of n+1 elements is created and then all the
  n elements are copied from the old array to the new array and then
  the new element is inserted in the new array.
- Adding n elements requires on time.
- The isEmpty, size, iterator, set, get and listIterator operations
  require the same amount of time, independently of element you access.
- Only Objects can be added to an ArrayList
- Permits null elements

If you need to add a large number of elements to an ArrayList, you can use the ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) operation to ensure that the ArrayList has that required capacity. This will ensure that the Array is copied only once when all the elements are added and increase the performance of addition of elements to an ArrayList. Also inserting an element in the middle of say 1000 elements would require you to move 500 elements up or down and then add the element in the middle.

The benefit of using ArrayList is that accessing random elements is cheap and is not affected by the number of elemets in the ArrayList. But addition of elements to the head of tail or in the middle is costly.

**Vector** is similar to ArrayList with the difference that it is synchronized. It offers some other benefits like it has an initial capacity and an incremental capacity. So if your vector has a capacity of 10 and incremental capacity of 10, then when you are adding the 11th element a new Vector would be created with 20 elements and the 11 elements would be copied to the new Vector. So addition of 12th to 20th elements would not require creation of new vector.

By default, when a vector needs to grow the size of its internal data structure to hold more elements, the size of internal data structure is doubled, whereas for ArrayList the size is increased by only 50%. So ArrayList is more conservative in terms of space.

**LinkedList** is much more flexible and lets you insert, add and remove elements from both sides of your collection - it can be used as queue and even double-ended queue! Internally a LinkedList does not use arrays. LinkedList is a sequence of nodes, which are double linked. Each node contains header, where actually objects are stored, and two links or pointers to next or previous node. A LinkedList looks like a chain, consisting of people who hold each other's hand. You can insert people or node into that chain or remove. Linked lists permit node insert/remove operation at any point in the list in constant time.

So inserting elements in linked list (whether at head or at tail or in the middle) is not expensive. Also when you retrieve elements from the head it is cheap. But when you want to randomly access the elements of the linked list or access the elements at the tail of the list then the operations are heavy. Cause, for accessing the n+1 th element, you will need to parse through the first n elements to reach the n+1th element.

Also linked list is not synchronized. So multiple threads modifying and reading the list would need to be synchronized externally.

So the choice of which class to use for creating lists depends on the requirements. ArrayList or Vector( if you need synchronization ) could be used when you need to add elements at the end of the list and access elements randomly - more access operations than add operations. Whereas a LinkedList should be used when you need to do a lot of add/delete (elements) operations from the head or the middle of the list and your access operations are comparatively less.

Comment: "But its constant size provides efficiency" -> not true, depends on what you need to do with it (insert, search, loop, ...).

Comment: sorry. I meant - The constant size provides efficiency when you know the number of elements available with you.

Comment: No true either. Again, depends on what you want to do with them. If I need to remove an element, I know exactly how many elements I have and how many I will have, but that is not efficient with an array.

Comment: Same goes for a search operation. Inefficient in an array, even if you know the number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the notification. :)